# Facing issue in authentication

Tags: authentication, jmeter

I am doing performance testing  for restricted websites using jmeter, so I  made changes in Krb5.conf , jass.conf files and now I am able to record and replay the applications but for one application during replay 401 unauthorized error is coming. Need your suggestions please

Comment: Please provide the LoadRunner context for this question to match the tag

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your domain/[KDC](https://gerardnico.com/security/auth/kerberos/kdc) configuration it is not possible to come up with the [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) and associated files setup instructions.

First of all enable Kerberos debugging in Java, it can be done my adding the next line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
sun.security.krb5.debug=true
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

Once you will get more information regarding what exactly fails and where - you will be able to amend JMeter configuration accordingly.

References:

- [Introduction to JAAS and Java GSS-API Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/)
- [Kerberos Throubleshooting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/Troubleshooting.html)
- [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter/)